# Generating a document by group count and displaying the result in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I have a requirement to group documents by count based on a particular field:

So for example if you have the following three documents:

```
   <doc>
          <id>1</id>
          <category>food</category>
          <body>car</body>
   </doc>
   <doc>
          <id>2</id>
          <category>travel</category>
          <body>car</body>
   </doc>
   <doc>
          <id>3</id>
          <category>food</category>
          <body>car</body>
   </doc>
```

A search with the query string 'car' based on a grouping based on the 'category' field should return something like:

```
   <doc>
          <id>1</id>
          <category>food</category>
          <body>car</body>
          <category_count>2</category_count>
   </doc>
   <doc>
          <id>2</id>
          <category>travel</category>
          <body>car</body>
          <category_count>1</category_count>
   </doc>
   <doc>
          <id>3</id>
          <category>food</category>
          <body>car</body>
          <category_count>2</category_count>
   </doc>
```

How to archive this in Solr ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check solr Result Grouping .

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping

Comment: No. i am not looking for grouped results. i want results in actual order and count inside that as shown above

Comment: do you mean you want facets  ?